# Django Admin: list_display() order by count of related object

Tags: django, django-admin

Imagine you have a model `Person` which can have N `Book` instances.

I want to display the number of books a person has in the django admin change-list view.

It is easy to display the number (write a custom method on PersonAdmin).

But I could not find a way to make it sortable by the number of books a person has.

I read the docs for [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), but could not find an answer.

According to the docs a query expression could be used. Is it possible to solve it this way?

After applying the answer, this is what it looks like. In this case each instance has N log entries:

[image: order-by-log-count]

Comment: I believe you'd need to sort that in your custom method?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override the **`get_queryset()`** method of model admin with the help of **`annoate()`** and **`order_by()`** methods. Then, define a callable function(**book_count()**) to return the value to the change-list page

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('book_count', 'other_field')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(book_count=Count('book')).order_by('-book_count')
        return qs

    def book_count(self, person_instance):
        return person_instance.book_count

    book_count.admin_order_field = 'book_count'
```

#### Why I didn't add **`ordering`** ?

While we calling the **`super()`**, Django will throw exceptions

Comment: To make it really sortable shouldn't you also add: book_count.admin_order_field = 'book_count'

Comment: Also see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: @JPG one thing I could not get to work: If the same admin has an `@admin.action` where you want to modify the entire queryset, e.g. `queryset.update(something=True)` you'll get errors about the "book_count" field not existing — I suppose it is expecting such a field to write to because it is now in the queryset. (Iterating the queryset and setting `something=True` on each entry works, but not when using the modified queryset.